# Is it possible to get a faculty position from a skype interview alone?

Tags: postdocs, faculty-application, interview

I am applying for faculty positions in a country outside the country I am currently a postdoc in (USA). My visa restrictions make it difficult traveling outside of the US for interviews.

Is it possible to get a faculty position from a skype interview alone?

Answer (score 3):

Possible? Yes, of course. Assuming your other materials are solid and you are high on the list of applicants. Not the common thing and not the best route, but if your restrictions are understood by the hiring committee it might be possible to get an offer if you come over well in such an interview.

But you may not have many alternatives, so it may be your best bet.